# Cannot understand solution (Turing Machine & Reduction)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-mathematics, turing-machines

[Photo of my problem that I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUuZE.jpg)

About question above in photo, I just can't understand its solution provided.

We know the complement of Atm = {`<M,W>` : M is TM and M does not accept W}
and Rtm as described in photo = {`<M,W>` : M is TM that rejects the input string W}

if we put `M,epsilon` into each of above,

```
the complement of Atm = M does not accept epsilon
Rtm = M rejects Epsilon
```

in either case, it makes sense to me, thus my perspective is
`<M,epsilon>` is in Rtm and also in complement of Atm.
But answer says `<M,epsilon>` is NOT in Rtm but in complement of Atm

Why is that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that there are three possible things a Turing machine can do (eventually) on a given input string:

- Accept,
- Reject,
- Not halt (that is, run forever without giving an answer).

This means there are two ways a pair $\langle M, w\rangle$ can fail to be in $A_{TM}$:

- $M(w)$ halts and says "REJECT," or
- $M(w)$ never halts.

In the former case, we have $\langle M, w\rangle\in R_{TM}$. But in the latter case, $\langle M, w\rangle$ is in neither $R_{TM}$ or $A_{TM}$. What is true is that $\overline{A_{TM}}\supseteq R_{TM}$, but they are not equal.